# Superscript to PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, rtf

I'm looking for a solution, either paid or free...

I have superscript text stored in SQL in RTF format, I need to print the superscript on a PDF document along with other text. So for example the PDF doc might read "Equation 1:" and then print the superscript text extracted from SQL.

I have been searching for an easy way to do this and so far come up empty.

The current PDF docs are made with PDFSharp but i'm happy to change that for a workable solution.

I thought of converting the rtf to an image with PdfConverter and then placing the image on the pdf doc but that doesn't seem to work.

I tried to do this with the following code however it throws an error "Parameter is not valid".

```
PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
byte[] rtfstring = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromRtfString(spec);
ImageConverter conv = new ImageConverter();
Image i = (Image)conv.ConvertFrom(rtfstring);
```

Comment: When you say superscript, you mean ˢᵘᵖᵉʳˢᶜʳᶦᵖᵗ, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, an example would be <104cfu/g (where the 4 is in superscript)